# font-size changes in Chrome iPhone5 view

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

This is my code for testing font-size in desktop view and mobile view. I use Chrome Inspector to toggle between desktop view and iphone5 view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>html5 font test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <style type="text/css">
    body, html {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a arcu sed massa finibus dapibus ac sed erat. Phasellus eget magna lectus. Curabitur lectus augue, porta ac faucibus a, efficitur et mi. Phasellus id purus maximus sem placerat varius et luctus eros. Donec maximus odio at erat facilisis, id lacinia erat imperdiet. Cras lacinia orci sed nisl gravida vestibulum. Aliquam dignissim nisl ut auctor rhoncus. Nam congue, diam quis ultrices iaculis, mi purus mollis libero, sit amet egestas nulla justo vel dui. Ut pharetra bibendum lorem, eget rutrum mi scelerisque id. Nullam feugiat condimentum cursus. In at fringilla augue.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is p tag font-size is 18px in desktop, but changes to 51px in iphone5 view. When I adjust the width of the browser window, the font-size remains 18px, but when switching to iPhone5 view, the font-size changes to 51px.

Here is Chrome iPhone5 mobile view computed font-size

[image]

Here is desktop computed font-size

[image]

How does this happen?

If you go to www.wordpress.com, their computed font-size only changes from 20px to 16px, when viewed in Chrome device simulator. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your head section `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`. It basically forces the mobile browser to render the page at the width of it's own screen size. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) is an article explaining what it does in more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, the font-size remains 18px in iPhone5 view, but Why rending at its own device width, 320px, will keep the computed font-size from changing?

Comment: I think it's because mobile devices by default try to compensate for websites that aren't mobile friendly, by adjusting fonts size to make the text more legible for example.